# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when removeAllObject

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a class named UICustomLabel with a variable NSMutableString : _text . I created a lot of this objects to display the content as page. Here is code to create :

```
for (int i = 0; i < linesOfFirstPage; i++) //first page is the special case 
            {
                UICustomLabel * _centerLabel =[[UICustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 555 + 35 * i, 575.0, 35.0)];//create label in follow kPortraitIpadfirstLabelRect area
                if (!_isSmallFont) _centerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 505 + 45 * i, 575, 45);
                _centerLabel._textColor=kLabelTextColor;
                _centerLabel._backgroundColor=kBackgroundColor;
                _centerLabel._font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:isSmallFont?25:32];
                [_contentOfPage addObject:_centerLabel];
                [self addSubview:_centerLabel];
                [_centerLabel release];
            }
```

After that when i want to remove all Label in my page :

> ```
>       if (_contentOfPage)
>         {
>             for (int i = 0; i < [_contentOfPage count]; i++)
>             {
>                 UICustomLabel * tmp = [_contentOfPage objectAtIndex:i];
>                 [tmp removeFromSuperview];
>             }
>             [_contentOfPage removeAllObjects];
>         }
> ```

But i get an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS when command [_contentOfPage removeAllObjects] excuted; When i reject the command [_text release] in the method dealloc of UICustomLabel, the program running fine. So what was the reason?

Comment: show where you create _text. Because most likely this will be the reason for the exception. I think you release it without retaining it before.

Comment: I created _text in init method of UICustomLabel : _text = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];. After that when i want to set value i used [_text setString:str];

Comment: Use Instruments.app with the "Zombie" instrument. It's very likely that it will uncover an over-release.

Comment: And now i tried to remove the command [_centerLabel release] when init UICustomLabel(you can see that in the first code paragraph). It's fine. So the reason is release a lot?

Comment: What's the type of `_contentOfPage`?

Comment: Have you overridden `addSubview:`? The UI "namespace" is Apple's baby, so you shouldn't use it lest Apple someday write their own `UICustomLabel`. Prifixing `_centerLabel` with an underscore doesn't seem likely to be a consistent naming convention, given that you have another local (`tmp`) without an underscore. Also, underscore prefixes generally denote non-public fields.

Comment: Thanks all of your help. I used Zombie and seen my problem : _text = [_text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]; How to mark the question as reslved.

Comment: You can update your question with the problematic code (as your question doesn't currently have code that [reproduces the problem](http://sscce.org/)), then post an answer and self accept.